# Can I use Solid Fill or Gradient Like Smart Objects

Tags: photoshop

Photoshop gives a lot of power for web designers using smart objects. I can create re-usable elements like buttons, drop downs etc. using smart objects and sue them across a project. Later if I need to make a change, I can only edit that smart object and the change will show everywhere I have used that smart object. Can I use some same mechanism with colorus and fill also? What I want to achieve is lets say use Orange colour as base colour in my design, later if the client wants green colour, I want to change that orange colour at one place and somehow change it everywhere. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Moved my question to the sister Graphic Designing site. Therefore I am closing this one.

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38064/can-i-use-solid-fill-or-gradient-like-smart-objects

Comment: Not sure how to close this question? Or should I leave it open?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphic design & OP has duplicated the question on a graphic site on the stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do through Shape Layer or Layer Comps.